# Why is the MLFlow UI different on installation?

Tags: mlflow

My MLFlow installation results in a significantly different UI experience  that does not neatly stack the Parameters and Metrics columns as in the QuickStart.

Here's what my UI looks like after logging some basic information:

[image]

Whereas every other example of MLFlow I've come across online looks like this (image taken from MLFlow website quickstart): 
[image]

The other thing that's missing is the toggle between "list" and "table" views. Below is what MLFlow documentation says I should see: 
[image]

Whereas here's what I see in my installation: 
[image]

My environments are as follows:

1. Ubuntu 16.04, Docker + pip installation of MLFlow
2. Mac OS,

   1. Conda + pip installation of MLFlow
   2. Brew installation of Python, then pip3 installation of MLFlow

I've tried tweaking the following:

1. Version of MLFlow from 1.3 to 1.4
2. Version of Python from 3.7 to 3.8
3. Brand new installation vs. existing upgrade

I'm out of ideas at this point as to why my UI looks so different. It doesn't necessarily affect my usage of MLFlow, but I'm trying to sell it to my colleagues as a good experiment tracking system and I want the UI to be the best possible representation.

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***

Figured it out -- in the runs table, click one of the parameters or metrics, and select [Display as a separate column] from the dropdown to get a column of barchart values ala excel conditional formatting. (mlflow v1.5)

[image: Dropdown selector]

---

---

***Original Answer***

Observe the same UI as you, suspect that certain snapshots are of an unreleased MLFlow version, or [the managed databricks version](https://databricks.com/product/managed-mlflow).

The model registry model overview page has a screenshot which shows a serving icon, which I've not been able to find further documentation on...

[image: The model registry model overview page has a screenshot which shows a serving button, which I've not been able to find further documentation on either...]